# How to configure Spring Data Rest with SLF4J and log4j properly?

Tags: spring, log4j, slf4j, spring-data-rest

I have an issue with a Spring Data Rest application and a SLF4J configuration that is not working.

Spring Data Rest imports SLF4J within his native dependencies.

I'm trying to configure the Spring Data Rest application with log4j, **but it doesn't work**.

In my `pom.xml` I have excluded `commons-logging` adding this exclusion for every dependency:

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

This is the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>${artifactId}</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
        <param-value>data.rest.app</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/spring-web-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>restFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>mypackage.filter.RestFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>restFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>mypackage.loader.AppRepositoryRestDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

And this is the `log4j.properties`:

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, stdout

log4j.category.org.springframework=TRACE

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%X{principal}] %C.%M:%L (%t) - %m%n
```

Despite this configuration with **"TRACE"** level for Spring, **Spring Data Rest doesn't log anything with my configuration**.

This is the log that I can see at the start of the application:

```
INFORMATIONS: Initializing log4j from [C:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp5\wtpwebapps\data.rest.app\WEB-INF\log4j.properties]
aug 01, 2016 11:47:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMATIONS: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
aug 01, 2016 11:47:13 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFORMATIONS: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
```

I would expect that the "`initWebApplicationContext`" method of the `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader` would log as my Log4J configuration, but **it logs in the standard way ignoring my configuration**.

The same `log4j.properties` works perfectly with a **Spring MVC** configuration, but not with Spring Data Rest.

What's wrong/missing?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at log4j-over-slf4j at http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html  you should just have to add the dependency to your pom.xml

I used the spring-boot-sample-data-rest-archetype as a test and modified the dependencies as below

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: It's not necessary and it's not the origin of the issue. Spring Data Rest has SLF4J in its own dependencies, so the project inherits it. My Maven Dependencies in Eclipse are the following:
`C:\Users\ale\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.21\slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar`
`C:\Users\ale\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.21\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar`
`C:\Users\ale\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-jdk14\1.7.14\slf4j-jdk14-1.7.14.jar`; SLF4J it's already present.

Comment: Thanks in any case, I have found the way to solve the issue.

Comment: Just updated my answer, I think you just found the same thing.

Comment: Yeah... I notice that there are some conflicts between the artifacts, so it needs some exclusions in the pom.xml; not very intuitive, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution, thanks to @Essex Boy for the suggestion.

The solution is a combination of Essex Boy suggestion and a further exclusion to add in the pom.xml.

I had to add this following exclusion:

```
<exclusion>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

I had to add this exclusion because for some reasons a dependency in my project uses slf4j-jdk14.

Then, I added the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>
```

With both of these two configurations, Spring Data Rest magically starts to log with log4j and the custom configuration.

That's because the system at the start loaded the org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerFactory.
Without the exclusion, in the log we can see this warning:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp5/wtpwebapps/data.rest.app/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-jdk14-1.7.14.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp5/wtpwebapps/data.rest.app/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerFactory]
```